# Refresh flutter FUTUREBUILDER with a swipe up

Tags: flutter

I have an app that gets some data from firebase and than calls a class to display a widget based on the data from firebase. I tried adding a swipe up refresh but i have no idea where to put it and what to to call on refresh. I was trying it using the RefreshIndicator.

Here i will put my code in which it calls the database(firebase) and than creates an widget for each event in the database.

If you need any more information, please feel free to comment. Thank you so much for the help!

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: databaseReference.once(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
        List lists = [];
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        lists.clear();
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
        values.forEach((key, values) {
            lists.add(values);
        });
        return new ListView.builder(
          primary: false,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:12.0,right:12,bottom: 15,),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: lists.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if(lists[index]["Status"]== "Active"){;
          return Container(
          child:EvendWidget(lists[index]["EventImage"], 
                Text(lists[index]["EventName"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["EventLocation"]+ ", "+lists[index] 
                ["EventCounty"] ).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Date"]+ ", "+lists[index]["Time"]+ 
                " - "+lists[index]["Time"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Duration"]+ " H").data,
                Text(lists[index]["Genre"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Price"]).data,false));}else{return 
                SizedBox.shrink(); };
            });
        }
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
          child:CircularProgressIndicator());
    }),
```

If you need any more information, please feel free to comment. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Call `setState` in swipe action. It triggers `build` method in widget and call your future again.

```dart
onRefresh: () {
  setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: and what do i call in the setate?

Comment: You just call it. `setState` without actions also works. After you called it widget rebuilds and `build` method (where you working with `FutureBuilder`) called again.

Comment: and how do i check for a swipe action?

Comment: https://medium.com/codechai/adding-swipe-to-refresh-to-flutter-app-b234534f39a7

Comment: Can you add code of function that passed to `onRefresh` parameter in `RefreshIndicator`?

Comment: i think databaseReference.once(),

Comment: and i have to add the whole page in the body in the RefreshIndicator?

Answer (score 1):

```
RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () {
          return Future(() { setState(() {}); });
        },
        child: FutureBuilder(
        ...
```

Will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use RefreshIndicator for swipe to refresh.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html

use ListView.Builder as child of RefreshIndicator and in onRfresh use your future method

like this:

```
//define in widget
var refreshkey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

FutureBuilder(
  future: databaseReference.once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
    List lists = [];
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
    lists.clear();
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
    values.forEach((key, values) {
        lists.add(values);
    });
    return RefreshIndicator(
        key: refreshkey,
        onRefresh: databaseReference.once(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          primary: false,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:12.0,right:12,bottom: 15,),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: lists.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if(lists[index]["Status"]== "Active"){;
          return Container(
          child:EvendWidget(lists[index]["EventImage"], 
                Text(lists[index]["EventName"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["EventLocation"]+ ", "+lists[index] 
                ["EventCounty"] ).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Date"]+ ", "+lists[index]["Time"]+ 
                " - "+lists[index]["Time"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Duration"]+ " H").data,
                Text(lists[index]["Genre"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Price"]).data,false));}else{return 
                SizedBox.shrink(); };
        });
    )
      
    }
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
      child:CircularProgressIndicator());
}),
```

maybe need some edit.

Comment: i added the exact code and changed some stuff so it works but it does nothing on swipe up, it loads correctly but nothing happens when i swipe, no refresh indicator nothing

Comment: RefreshIndicator is default for pull down and it refresh the page but if you want to refresh the page for swipe up, maybe displacement property in RefreshIndicator  can help you (i'm not sure).

you can see this two link for more information:

https://medium.com/codechai/adding-swipe-to-refresh-to-flutter-app-b234534f39a7

https://medium.com/@maffan/implementing-pull-to-refresh-in-flutter-59dd31239624

Comment: yes, i ment pull down, but it has no action

Comment: you can set key in RefreshIndicator.

// define in widget
var refreshkey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

// use in widget
RefreshIndicator (
     key: refreshkey;
      ....
)


I edit the answer and add the key